# PHP - accessing a form-submitted file for validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, post

I've been doing form validation using $_POST for text entries. Now I have to validate uploaded files through the HTML type='file' forms. I'm having trouble accessing them through $_POST or $_FILES. Is there a different way to do this? I need to get the file so that I can check the MIME type using getimagesize() or mime_content_type()

Here are the relevant bits from my form:

```
<form action='submission.php' method='POST'>
    <p>Upload photo of professor</p>
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*>      
    <p>Upload video of professor</p>
    <input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*">
    <p><input type="submit" onclick="validate()"></p>
</form>
```

submission.php is supposed to call on a validation function to check that the MIME type is image, if I can get the file.

```
function validateimage(&$errors, $field_list, $field_name, $pattern) {
    if (isset($field_list[$field_name])) {
        if (!preg_match($pattern, mime_content_type($field_list[$field_name]))) {
            $errors[$field_name] = 'Please upload an image file';
        }
    } else {
        $errors[$field_name] = 'Required field';
    }
}
```

After adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my field and setting $field_list to $_FILES it almost works. However, it appears `isset($_FILES['pic'])` is always true, as when I try to submit with no upload, I get this warning:

`validateimage($errors, $_FILES, 'pic', '/^image/i');`

> Warning: mime_content_type(): Empty filename or path in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cs4ww3/Assignment 3/validate.inc.php on line 36

Comment: missing enctype in form

Comment: form sholud be <form action='submission.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @Shanukk Thanks! It's submitting and not giving me errors now, but it appears my validation isn't working as intended. Do you see any issues there?

Comment: -can you please show us your full code?

Comment: @Shanukk hhmmm... I think these are all the relevant parts, everything else might be too clunky. Basically I have an $errors array that I populate with different validation functions. If I have a form like `<input='text' name='username'>, after server-side validation, it creates an error as $errors['username']. You can see from the way I call validateimage() that it can't find the file from 'pic' in the first place

Answer (score 2):

In order for `$_FILES` to be populated with the submitted files, in your html you need to set `enctype` attr on your form to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form action='submission.php' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">

   ...

</form>
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. It's submitting and not giving me errors now, but it appears my validation isn't working as intended. Do you see any issues there?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you should try `mime_content_type($field_list[$field_name]['tmp_name])` in your if statement. this function expects file name and you are passing it an entire array.